# tsql- set options

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am rebuilding indexes using a script which reorganises or rebuilds indexes according to a predefined fill factor.

It is on SQl 2000.

I have the following SET options in my script:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

I am getting the following error:

DBCC failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT'

So, is it telling me that i should turn ANSI_WARNINGS OFF AND INCLUDE ARTHABORT TO ON?

I am confused with this.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to have:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
```

You can see more detail about this here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301292

When you move to SQL Server 2005+ you should use ALTER INDEX REBUILD/REORGANIZE as opposed to DBCC commands. Also, strongly suggest you check out SQLFool's and Ola's options, they can make your reindexing and rebuilding jobs much easier:  http://sqlfool.com/2009/06/index-defrag-script-v30/ and http://ola.hallengren.com/  I don't remember if either of these will work on 2000 but worth checking out.

Comment: Yes i use Michelle's (SQLFool) script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(SQL.80).aspx) for SQL Server 2000 (however, same applies to later versions):

> Note:  `ANSI_NULLS` is one of seven SET
>   options that must be set to required
>   values when dealing with indexes on
>   computed columns or indexed views. The
>   options `ANSI_PADDING`, `ANSI_WARNINGS`,
>   `ARITHABORT`, `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`, and
>   `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` also must be
>   set to ON, while `NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT`
>   must be set to OFF.

So, both should be ON

Comment: Thank you very much. Does it mean that I should include others too? like concat....etc